# Erro ao conectar no Firebird 2.5 (64 bits) no Delphi XE3

Tags: delphi, firebird, conexão

Estou com o seguinte erro ao conectar no Firebird 2.5 (64 bits) no Delphi XE3:

> DBX Error: Driver could not be properly initialized. Client library may be missing, not installed properly, of the wrong version, or the driver may be missing from the system path firebird

Já tentei colocar a DLL `fbclient` nas pastas `system32` e `syswow64` mas continuo com o mesmo erro.

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: vc ja colocou as `icuXX30.dll` na pasta?

Comment: a proposito, vc quer usar o firebird embedded ou vc instalou ele?

Comment: Para testes, já colocou a dll na mesma pasta do executável? Conferiu se o serviço do servidor está executando?
Conferiu se a porta que o servidor foi instalado é a mesma que está tentando conectar?
Como está configurada a connection no delphi? ele pode procurar pelas gds32 ou pela fbClient

Answer (score 2):

Se a aplicação que você está gerando no Delphi é 32bits, ela terá que carregar a versão 32bits do fbclient.dll. A fbclient.dll que está na pasta bin do Firebird 2.5 64bits é 64bits, portanto, não adianta copiar ela no SysWow64. Tenha certeza que o Delphi e sua aplicação estão carregando a versão certa da dll. Não me recordo se o instalador oficial do FB 2.5 64bits também grava a versão 32bits da DLL em alguma pasta. Se não gravar, então baixe o zip kit do FB 2.5 32bits e pegue a fbclient.dll 32bits de lá.

Para mais informações, veja http://www.firebase.com.br/fb/artigo.php?id=2419

Answer (score 0):

*Pode ser a versão diferente (inferior ao da aplicação)
* O servidor firebird não está istalado ou nao está inicializado

Tenta instalar o Firebird na versão de preferencia igual a do banco da aplicação.